# Signed up for Google Compute Engine without knowing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-billing

Hello Community Support

I signed up for the Google Compute Engine and did not realise that I would be charged $1000. The payment did not go through as there is not enough money on my credit card and I cannot pay the balance.

I didnt want to phone Google Support as they may hassle me for payment

Can you make any suggestions for a way to resolve this?

Thanks
sas

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware that this is not a Google service, it is a technical knowledge base for developers, and that therefore no-one here will be able to help you unfortunately.

Comment: There may be a legally enforceable cooling off period for online sales in your country, there is in the UK. Worth a look.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming.  Contact Google Cloud support for billing questions.

Answer (score 5):

Google provides free support for Google Cloud billing questions - contact them.

[Google Cloud Billing Support](https://support.google.com/cloud/troubleshooter/3511991?hl=en)

> I signed up for the Google Compute Engine and did not realise that I
>   would be charged $1000.

Google Cloud will automatically charge your card when you reach thresholds. The default for new accounts is $100.00 USD. Were you charged $100.00?

Additionally Google implements quotas for Compute resources. What type of resouce did you create that incurred $1,000.00 in charges? This would have exceeded your new account quota limit, so I wonder how you accomplished this ...

There is something odd about your first credit card charge being $1,000 USD as you should have received a number of charges for $100.00 each. After a credit card payment fails, you will receive billing payment notices. None of this would have happened mysteriously unless you do not read your email or SPAM filters blocked the notices.

Always take the time to learn what cloud resources cost. Understand that pricing, billing, resources and usage are important items not to be overlooked. Google, like most companies, is in the business to provide services and products that customers want and to make a profit while doing so.